# Editing the Batch entry form/template fields

Tags: civicontribute, civicampaign, batches

I am looking at the batch data entry form and wondering if it is possible to modify this:

[image: Batch data entry]

For example, I'd like to remove some columns (e.g. *Invoice ID*) and add others (e.g. *Campaign*).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was overthinking this and missed the memo in green in my own screenshot. Another case where the solution is in the Reserved Profiles.

**Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles > Reserved Profiles > Contribution Bulk Entry**

[image: Profile Contribution Bulk Entry]